# getValidator using RPC (NEAR)

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

How can I get my validator's information with RPC? (using my address)

I can't find it on official docs. https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc

Is it not supported yet?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? Are you referring to the staking pool details like fee and number of delegators? Or staking pool meta information like county, homepage url, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Endpoint to retrieve all the validators and available information is documented and you can try it out https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc#validation-status

Basically using HTTPie:

`http post https://rpc.testnet.near.org jsonrpc=2.0 method=validators params:='[null]' id=dontcare`

Example response is also documented:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "current_validators": [
      {
        "account_id": "01node.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3iNqnvBgxJPXCxu6hNdvJso1PEAc1miAD35KQMBCA3aL",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "176429739989396285019500901780",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "alexandruast.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:A3XJ3uVGxSi9o2gnG2r8Ra3fqqodRpL4iuLTc6fNdGUj",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "151430394143736014372434860532",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "aquarius.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8NfEarjStDYjJTwKUgQGy7Z7UTGsZaPhTUsExheQN3r1",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "130367563121508828296664196836",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bazilik.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3pDJwDQ6Y5B9QeW1jz8KunhZH4D4GQG86reTmrRfdD7c",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "169013447850997135034919151338",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 211,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bisontrails.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8g4P5EXyp2b2pfVMHY1QLfkRcY59hjPfWrFCKUWX3RmR",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "184162578269044826045352223479",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bitcat.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:9mtnwPQyyap1QNH9ag6r4the7Jkkpdyt9HUF5G1dWxKx",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "135215509376418353124295451543",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "blazenet.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:DiogP36wBXKFpFeqirrxN8G2Mq9vnakgBvgnHdL9CcN3",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "137364229255641651855065314186",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "certusone.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:CKW7f41Kn8YCDPzaGLs1MrPb9h3BjQmHhbei6Ff6nRRF",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "176644821310043228577017742667",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "chorus-one.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:6LFwyEEsqhuDxorWfsKcPPs324zLWTaoqk4o6RDXN7Qc",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "110397600457815316527526651811",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "cloudpost.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:AVVLmJDG8z6UgmW9fmJGVFTdYxxfnqXH6c7FVQmhE6dp",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "136597929514591130855076834167",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "dokia.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:935JMz1vLcJxFApG3TY4MA4RHhvResvoGwCrQoJxHPn9",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "220445043066799898276306006919",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 426,
        "num_expected_blocks": 426
      },
      {
        "account_id": "dsrvlabs.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:61ei2efmmLkeDR1CG6JDEC2U3oZCUuC2K1X16Vmxrud9",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "161508967845718247649113721019",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "fresh_lockup.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:7CMFLtEohojtxBkmj9Jb6AGgbphb1zvxymHzpzuyCjfG",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "193574159400241036715020269158",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "inotel.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:C55jH1MCHYGa3tzUyZZdGrJmmCLP22Aa4v88KYpn2xwZ",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "178598870951670469578754984993",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "jazza.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:85cPMNVrqUz8N7oWbbvWbUuamHcJNe49uRbaSzftLCz9",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "155762349362951827286303475797",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "joe1.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:G3SxwzmiEZSm3bHnTLtxJvm3NvT1TLQcWuV1iod6i6NJ",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "129230772267511696840933436174",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "kronos.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3i2pertqzF8xqkJ4BrE4t4r67YiYYrUKCktbqvDgjzuQ",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "144544279093485390569527924033",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 202,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "kytzu.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:61tgPZpy8tqFeAwG4vtf2ZKCRoENiP2A1TJVWEwnbxZU",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "113758432843198726378418342568",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "lowfeevalidation.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:EXyjSMGSnk5uGphF3gVV1jCudaAudbW8imoEccYEJg3V",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "113685537557977098595863252617",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "lunanova.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:2fZ59qfo9QHNLijoht9cwUb9enSNcnRmXbQn1gKZxvkw",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "172903039219549397267702571804",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "moonlet.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3e1nVCVGNS3yr6CcUvpDAs3BhiWtyM9uTBWkyVR5Xn3K",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "140599784944681716744261599779",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:7PGseFbWxvYVgZ89K1uTJKYoKetWs7BJtbyXDzfbAcqX",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "1907234923845608896091985071588",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 3614,
        "num_expected_blocks": 3616
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node1",
        "public_key": "ed25519:6DSjZ8mvsRZDvFqFxo8tCKePG96omXW7eVYVSySmDk8e",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "1906065501889463342906704128820",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 3613,
        "num_expected_blocks": 3614
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node2",
        "public_key": "ed25519:GkDv7nSMS3xcqA45cpMvFmfV1o4fRF6zYo1JRR6mNqg5",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "1840271519773089248112279578450",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 3615,
        "num_expected_blocks": 3615
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node3",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ydgzeXHJ5Xyt7M1gXLxqLBW1Ejx6scNV5Nx2pxFM8su",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "1247270566437910246525604113433",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 2335,
        "num_expected_blocks": 2342
      },
      {
        "account_id": "nodeasy.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:25Dhg8NBvQhsVTuugav3t1To1X1zKiomDmnh8yN9hHMb",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "131652957125263756523827257067",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "northernlights.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:CsMecqKCfagnebMB3ha1uRubay5Z4V85req23bNAJSG3",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "159669819380982417675619400525",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "orangeclub.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:HezFeSzcwuR5wvkqccgMCMnpf1eQkVCfk52tXZEdKZHz",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "143971234567521206686862639104",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "pathrock.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:G138GdQsU7PdFLD6X88NmTLAEDR7agPcq9HLZqGpegkm",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "125204431569306697735287326827",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "pool_easy2stake.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8nzKxvmyeauQRehWkby8GfWNLgqPiF5FCRFSD75M1Rwh",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "176893731686620703671521068552",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "sl1sub.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3URBpNUjNAMzugQH1rdSKMtwFM8AwHaJgZk5Z6YtnfFL",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "155741680601335529540438949153",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staked.pool.6fb1358",
        "public_key": "ed25519:684rMbuVYYgL2CkmYgC1weLh3erd2bwrmtQtJJhWzPwj",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "126911347639167461321544980789",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staked.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:D2afKYVaKQ1LGiWbMAZRfkKLgqimTR74wvtESvjx5Ft2",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "140558085958535444819294942478",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "stakin.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:GvddxjaxBCqGGB4kMNWNFtvozU1EEZ2jrnggKZW8LaU4",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "122221693837484004905170552626",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staking-power.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:4s79F6Fdjgb3rHXPLwaXZG4Hq7Za8nogUu3vXEamRBQo",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "113293334165305165414435157738",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "syncnode.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:FUAVDkmLhuTbKYv4GWuWv9ogjKzRatLd5ZBMKXRy7WqE",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "133414422809248011010747790387",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 212,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      },
      {
        "account_id": "thepassivetrust.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:4NccD2DNJpBkDmWeJ2GbqPoivQ93qcKiR4PHALJKCTod",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "162714097201953456968339272308",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "top.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:FR5qxAsP8GgXDN96pappLtWMywiqWsPVqT3HLE3YaUx",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "164760602493727447176131601464",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "valeraverim.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3686ABqNUZc1qhLWLHg5xZpBzrWPiUCMNZxcCNmg3e2s",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "191733144511459134091274432419",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "zainy.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:37KfhBNYjqpaUVh3ft5kPcFn3xK1eVvtDZJCQQVCGnzQ",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "113441017844444454951489924484",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 213,
        "num_expected_blocks": 213
      },
      {
        "account_id": "zpool.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ETFRFNHfvd6fpj74MGYYQp3diY8WB4bFmWMxjTB2yY4V",
        "is_slashed": false,
        "stake": "140932616764414290525265048028",
        "shards": [0],
        "num_produced_blocks": 120,
        "num_expected_blocks": 212
      }
    ],
    "next_validators": [
      {
        "account_id": "01node.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3iNqnvBgxJPXCxu6hNdvJso1PEAc1miAD35KQMBCA3aL",
        "stake": "177341160716540400974121040893",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "alexandruast.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:A3XJ3uVGxSi9o2gnG2r8Ra3fqqodRpL4iuLTc6fNdGUj",
        "stake": "152212670433756011274558210225",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "aquarius.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8NfEarjStDYjJTwKUgQGy7Z7UTGsZaPhTUsExheQN3r1",
        "stake": "131041030638338742265060835987",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bazilik.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3pDJwDQ6Y5B9QeW1jz8KunhZH4D4GQG86reTmrRfdD7c",
        "stake": "169886556654364796730036727847",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bisontrails.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8g4P5EXyp2b2pfVMHY1QLfkRcY59hjPfWrFCKUWX3RmR",
        "stake": "185113946165399113822995097304",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bitcat.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:9mtnwPQyyap1QNH9ag6r4the7Jkkpdyt9HUF5G1dWxKx",
        "stake": "135914020962862866419944507506",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "blazenet.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:DiogP36wBXKFpFeqirrxN8G2Mq9vnakgBvgnHdL9CcN3",
        "stake": "138073840925159254185212483041",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "certusone.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:CKW7f41Kn8YCDPzaGLs1MrPb9h3BjQmHhbei6Ff6nRRF",
        "stake": "177557353126393581856047095474",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "chorus-one.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:6LFwyEEsqhuDxorWfsKcPPs324zLWTaoqk4o6RDXN7Qc",
        "stake": "110967904880664326100649881128",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "cloudpost.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:AVVLmJDG8z6UgmW9fmJGVFTdYxxfnqXH6c7FVQmhE6dp",
        "stake": "137303582563490110045159846741",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "dokia.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:935JMz1vLcJxFApG3TY4MA4RHhvResvoGwCrQoJxHPn9",
        "stake": "221583843027440134728813179120",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "dsrvlabs.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:61ei2efmmLkeDR1CG6JDEC2U3oZCUuC2K1X16Vmxrud9",
        "stake": "162343309156672629963246208215",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "fresh_lockup.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:7CMFLtEohojtxBkmj9Jb6AGgbphb1zvxymHzpzuyCjfG",
        "stake": "194574146707912827852030100603",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "inotel.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:C55jH1MCHYGa3tzUyZZdGrJmmCLP22Aa4v88KYpn2xwZ",
        "stake": "179521497218882663562358374377",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "jazza.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:85cPMNVrqUz8N7oWbbvWbUuamHcJNe49uRbaSzftLCz9",
        "stake": "156567004141558073310769195719",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "joe1.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:G3SxwzmiEZSm3bHnTLtxJvm3NvT1TLQcWuV1iod6i6NJ",
        "stake": "129898367221448376460128575495",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "kronos.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3i2pertqzF8xqkJ4BrE4t4r67YiYYrUKCktbqvDgjzuQ",
        "stake": "145291600307308103830278523851",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "kytzu.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:61tgPZpy8tqFeAwG4vtf2ZKCRoENiP2A1TJVWEwnbxZU",
        "stake": "114346099616381729581424582943",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "lowfeevalidation.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:EXyjSMGSnk5uGphF3gVV1jCudaAudbW8imoEccYEJg3V",
        "stake": "114272827178534171015566175242",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "lunanova.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:2fZ59qfo9QHNLijoht9cwUb9enSNcnRmXbQn1gKZxvkw",
        "stake": "173796241314359640924313305613",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "moonlet.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3e1nVCVGNS3yr6CcUvpDAs3BhiWtyM9uTBWkyVR5Xn3K",
        "stake": "141326111231422084384405939935",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:7PGseFbWxvYVgZ89K1uTJKYoKetWs7BJtbyXDzfbAcqX",
        "stake": "1917087533938315356792420553580",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node1",
        "public_key": "ed25519:6DSjZ8mvsRZDvFqFxo8tCKePG96omXW7eVYVSySmDk8e",
        "stake": "1915912070849706566898523265362",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node2",
        "public_key": "ed25519:GkDv7nSMS3xcqA45cpMvFmfV1o4fRF6zYo1JRR6mNqg5",
        "stake": "1849778202731933988446605407109",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "node3",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ydgzeXHJ5Xyt7M1gXLxqLBW1Ejx6scNV5Nx2pxFM8su",
        "stake": "1253713857932062021626652303305",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "nodeasy.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:25Dhg8NBvQhsVTuugav3t1To1X1zKiomDmnh8yN9hHMb",
        "stake": "132333065508677559475570461579",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "northernlights.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:CsMecqKCfagnebMB3ha1uRubay5Z4V85req23bNAJSG3",
        "stake": "160494659810582810750858869593",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "orangeclub.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:HezFeSzcwuR5wvkqccgMCMnpf1eQkVCfk52tXZEdKZHz",
        "stake": "144714977470413958038055754809",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "pathrock.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:G138GdQsU7PdFLD6X88NmTLAEDR7agPcq9HLZqGpegkm",
        "stake": "125851226796631921571804668732",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "pool_easy2stake.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:8nzKxvmyeauQRehWkby8GfWNLgqPiF5FCRFSD75M1Rwh",
        "stake": "177807549352374182247265978294",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "sl1sub.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3URBpNUjNAMzugQH1rdSKMtwFM8AwHaJgZk5Z6YtnfFL",
        "stake": "156546228606913052982706314599",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staked.pool.6fb1358",
        "public_key": "ed25519:684rMbuVYYgL2CkmYgC1weLh3erd2bwrmtQtJJhWzPwj",
        "stake": "127566960646771620637977634520",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staked.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:D2afKYVaKQ1LGiWbMAZRfkKLgqimTR74wvtESvjx5Ft2",
        "stake": "141284196855966747583242721111",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "stakin.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:GvddxjaxBCqGGB4kMNWNFtvozU1EEZ2jrnggKZW8LaU4",
        "stake": "122853080560791799567241762038",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "staking-power.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:4s79F6Fdjgb3rHXPLwaXZG4Hq7Za8nogUu3vXEamRBQo",
        "stake": "113878597697173990840757447344",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "syncnode.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:FUAVDkmLhuTbKYv4GWuWv9ogjKzRatLd5ZBMKXRy7WqE",
        "stake": "134103630138795323490241660174",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "thepassivetrust.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:4NccD2DNJpBkDmWeJ2GbqPoivQ93qcKiR4PHALJKCTod",
        "stake": "163554668234785516757420218799",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "top.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:FR5qxAsP8GgXDN96pappLtWMywiqWsPVqT3HLE3YaUx",
        "stake": "165611741467072665024638629174",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "valeraverim.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3686ABqNUZc1qhLWLHg5xZpBzrWPiUCMNZxcCNmg3e2s",
        "stake": "192723621295992295990275575014",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "zainy.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:37KfhBNYjqpaUVh3ft5kPcFn3xK1eVvtDZJCQQVCGnzQ",
        "stake": "114027175849273464802110072969",
        "shards": [0]
      },
      {
        "account_id": "zpool.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ETFRFNHfvd6fpj74MGYYQp3diY8WB4bFmWMxjTB2yY4V",
        "stake": "141660662431449802378487016195",
        "shards": [0]
      }
    ],
    "current_fishermen": [
      {
        "account_id": "staked.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:5VmCXxWepj22uFoKmrxk6DTiFa3fuTzDcwGxM8uUErpr",
        "stake": "5957256918881889179239884296"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bisontrails.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ED2v5KtScbk6aNjGcTn1YMDUu3EXfD5HPt1x6RiYBypk",
        "stake": "7679439354334034871130713908"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "cryptium.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:2usUkjmKWxQw7QUeFfELHCEqS2UxjwsRqnCkA5oQ6A2B",
        "stake": "6484546971716985483357166277"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "buildlinks3.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:Cfy8xjSsvVquSqo7W4A2bRX1vkLPycLgyCvFNs3Rz6bb",
        "stake": "81221864655530313350540629757"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "mmm.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3jEqDDKaJEg1r8UGu2x2dC55BXE7i26yNFQzvfJkkHkf",
        "stake": "80030001196381772535600000000"
      }
    ],
    "next_fishermen": [
      {
        "account_id": "staked.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:5VmCXxWepj22uFoKmrxk6DTiFa3fuTzDcwGxM8uUErpr",
        "stake": "5957256918881889179239884296"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "bisontrails.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:ED2v5KtScbk6aNjGcTn1YMDUu3EXfD5HPt1x6RiYBypk",
        "stake": "7679439354334034871130713908"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "cryptium.stakingpool",
        "public_key": "ed25519:2usUkjmKWxQw7QUeFfELHCEqS2UxjwsRqnCkA5oQ6A2B",
        "stake": "6484546971716985483357166277"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "buildlinks3.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:Cfy8xjSsvVquSqo7W4A2bRX1vkLPycLgyCvFNs3Rz6bb",
        "stake": "81221864655530313350540629757"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "mmm.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:3jEqDDKaJEg1r8UGu2x2dC55BXE7i26yNFQzvfJkkHkf",
        "stake": "80030001196381772535600000000"
      }
    ],
    "current_proposals": [
      {
        "account_id": "kytzu.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:61tgPZpy8tqFeAwG4vtf2ZKCRoENiP2A1TJVWEwnbxZU",
        "stake": "114346100195275968419224582943"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "nodeasy.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:25Dhg8NBvQhsVTuugav3t1To1X1zKiomDmnh8yN9hHMb",
        "stake": "132333066144809013154670461579"
      },
      {
        "account_id": "thepassivetrust.pool.f863973.m0",
        "public_key": "ed25519:4NccD2DNJpBkDmWeJ2GbqPoivQ93qcKiR4PHALJKCTod",
        "stake": "163554672455685458970920218837"
      }
    ],
    "prev_epoch_kickout": [],
    "epoch_start_height": 17754191
  },
  "id": "dontcare"
}
```

Comment: Actually, I mean the validator whom I staked my tokens. Not all the validators. But thanks for the additional information.

Comment: There is no endpoint to query only one validator, you get them all and then filter to the ones you are interested in.